# Issue with custom input field for number input in range format [low-high]

Tags: javascript, html-input, onkeyup

### Problem statement

Accept a **number** or a **valid range** within [1-N] where N is received from
previous page.

Conditions:

- Any number entered as input must be within [1 - N]
- Any range entered must be valid in [low - high] format and
  [1 < low < high < N]

**Prevent the invalid input dynamically.**

### Sample test cases

For N = 45 if input entered is

- 0 -> delete this as it is invalid, i.e. not within valid rangwe [1 - N]
- 46 -> delete the second digit '6' as it makes the number greater than N
- Any number between 1 and 45 is retained as it is valid number
- 13-14 or 12-24 accept this input as it meets [1 < low < high < N]
- 12-11 or 24-46 -> delete the last digit '1' or '6' as it makes the range
  invalid

### Issue

Difficult to enter a valid range input as it clips away the digit when
entering the 'high' number in range.

Works correctly when the first digit in 'high' number is held and second digit
is entered. This is due to `onkeyup` event not triggered for first digit in
'high' number.

### Code

https://jsfiddle.net/manid2/9onbdamj/5/

Needs some minor change I am not sure what it is as I don't
work primarily in front-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `setTimeout` this part, code will wait for a while before the evaluation.

```
    else if (KC_DIGITS.includes(key_pressed)) {
    let that = this
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if (!parseAndValidateOldVal(regex_res)) {
        console.log("text number value is invalid");
        $(that).val(function(i, val) {
          return val.slice(0, -1);
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
//mz_form_script.js

// global variables
const USER_UPPER_NUM = 45;
const KC_BACKSPACE = 8;
const KC_END = 35;
const KC_HOME = 36;
const KC_ARROW_KEYS = [37, 38, 39, 40];
const KC_NUMPAD_DASH = [109, 173, 189];
var _kc_digits = []; {
  // Digit0 to Digit9
  for (var i = 48; i < 58; ++i) {
    _kc_digits.push(i);
  }
  // Numpad0 to Numpad9
  for (var i = 96; i < 106; ++i) {
    _kc_digits.push(i);
  }
}
const KC_DIGITS = _kc_digits;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // insert num into para
  var user_input_num_p = $("#doc_user_input_p");
  user_input_num_p.text(USER_UPPER_NUM.toString());

  // restrict user input
  var user_input_num_t = $("#doc_cb_3_num_input_1");
  user_input_num_t.attr({
    placeholder: "1-" + Number(user_input_num_p.text()),
    min: 1,
    max: Number(user_input_num_p.text()),
  });
  user_input_num_t.keyup(handleDocCb3NumInput);
});

/**
 * To handle doc cb 3 user input
 *
 * @param {input} event
 */
function handleDocCb3NumInput(event) {
  const key_pressed = event.which;
  var old_val = $(this).val();

  console.log("key_pressed = " + key_pressed);
  console.log("old_val = " + old_val);

  // check for valid characters
  // TODO: below regex does not work correctly with onkeyup
  //(/^(\d{0,5}|\b(\d{0,5}-\d{0,5})\b)$/gm);
  var regex_res = old_val.match(/^(\d{0,5}|(\d{0,5}-\d{0,5}))$/g);
  if (null == regex_res) {
    console.log("regex is invalid, key: " + key_pressed);
    $(this).val(function(i, val) {
      return val.slice(0, -1);
    });
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("regex matched: " + regex_res);
  }

  var key_char = "";
  // valid ctrl keys
  if (
    KC_BACKSPACE == key_pressed ||
    KC_HOME == key_pressed ||
    KC_END == key_pressed ||
    KC_ARROW_KEYS.includes(key_pressed)
  ) {
    console.log("key_pressed is valid ctrl char");
  } else if (KC_NUMPAD_DASH.includes(key_pressed)) {
    key_char = "-";
    console.log("key_pressed is valid char: " + key_char);
  } else if (KC_DIGITS.includes(key_pressed)) {
    let that = this
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if (!parseAndValidateOldVal(regex_res)) {
        console.log("text number value is invalid");
        $(that).val(function(i, val) {
          return val.slice(0, -1);
        });
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  // invalid keys
  else {
    console.log("invalid key: " + key_pressed);
    $(this).val(function(i, val) {
      return val.slice(0, -1);
    });
  }
}

function parseAndValidateOldVal(regex_res) {
  var input_val = regex_res.toString();
  // is invalid
  if (input_val.startsWith("-") || input_val.endsWith("-")) {
    return false;
  }
  var input_val_num = Number(input_val);
  // is range and range is valid [1 < l < h < USER_UPPER_NUM]
  if (isNaN(input_val_num)) {
    var res = input_val.split("-", 2);
    var low = Number(res[0]);
    var high = Number(res[1]);
    if (low >= high || low < 1 || high > USER_UPPER_NUM) return false;
  }
  // is single number and [1 < val < USER_UPPER_NUM]
  else if (input_val_num < 1 || input_val_num > USER_UPPER_NUM) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>MZ form</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Handle form input dynamically</h1>

    <p>User input: <span id="doc_user_input_p" style="font-weight: bold;"></span></p>

    <form id="doc_cb_3" method="get">
      <input type="text" placeholder="1" id="doc_cb_3_num_input_1" name="doc_cb_3_num" />
      <button name="send" type="submit" value="ok">ok</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="mz_form_script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: hi @dolmushcu I tried this approach it works same, the last digit gets deleted after the deleted even if the input range is valid. Thanks for the suggestion. I think maybe this kind of validation should not be implemented.